# Running multiple animations in parallel and at the same time

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, parallel-processing

I am aware that this issue has already been raised, but the solutions offered ([such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3773823/multiple-animations-in-a-storyboard-at-the-same-time)) are insufficient for me.

I'd like to minimize my app window as shown below:
[image: Like this]

These are my codes (unnecessary codes have not been posted):

`XAML`:

```
<Window x:Name="GanjAsemanMainWindow" x:Class="Ganj_Aseman.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Ganj_Aseman"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Loaded="GanjAsemanMainWindow_Loaded" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" FontSize="13" Height="535" ResizeMode="CanResizeWithGrip" Title="MainWindow" Width="764" WindowStyle="None">
<Window.RenderTransform>
    <RotateTransform CenterX="{Binding}" CenterY="{Binding}" Angle="{Binding}"/>
</Window.RenderTransform>
<Window.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="WindowRotation">
        <DoubleAnimation BeginTime="00:00:00" SpeedRatio="0.9" Duration="00:00:2" Storyboard.TargetName="GanjAsemanMainWindow" From="0" To="360" AutoReverse="False" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.RenderTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"/>
    </Storyboard>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Image x:Name="MinimizeIconImage" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="MinimizeIconImage_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" MouseEnter="MinimizeIconImage_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="MinimizeIconImage_MouseLeave" GotFocus="MinimizeIconImage_GotFocus" LostFocus="MinimizeIconImage_LostFocus" Focusable="True" FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}" Cursor="Hand" Height="47"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Source="{Binding}" Margin="0,2,67,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="52">
        <Image.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ParallelTimeline BeginTime="00:00:00" SpeedRatio="0.9" Storyboard.TargetName="GanjAsemanMainWindow">
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:2" From="{Binding Path=ActualHeight,ElementName=GanjAsemanMainWindow}" To="0" AutoReverse="False" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:2" From="{Binding Path=ActualWidth,ElementName=GanjAsemanMainWindow}" To="0" AutoReverse="False" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width"/>
                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="00:00:2.5" From="100" To="0" AutoReverse="False" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"/>
                        </ParallelTimeline>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Image.Triggers>
    </Image>
</Grid>
```

`C#`:

```
private void MinimizeIconImage_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    RotateTransform RT = new RotateTransform(0, ActualWidth / 2, ActualHeight / 2);
    GanjAsemanMainWindow.RenderTransform = RT;
    (Resources["WindowRotation"] as Storyboard).Begin();
}
```

But, `DoubleAnimations` are performed sequentially rather than in parallel, and as a result, the following output is obtained:
[image: Output]

I think it will work fine if we can bind three properties to a `Storyboard.TargetProperty`.

I use the following tools:

- `.NET Framework 4.5`
- `WPF`

Thank you for your time.

Best regards,

Reza Jaferi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of animating the `Width` and `Height` of the Window, you may as well animate a `ScaleTransform`, similar to the `RotateTransform` that you already have. There is also no need for a ParallelTimeline.

You must however set the Window's `RenderTransformOrigin` property.

Here is a minimal example:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Class="WindowAnimationTest.MainWindow"
        Background="AliceBlue" Height="535" Width="764"
        AllowsTransparency="True" WindowStyle="None"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Window.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <RotateTransform/>
            <ScaleTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Window.RenderTransform>
    <Window.Resources>
        <Storyboard x:Key="MinimizeAnimations">
            <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Children[0].Angle"
                Duration="0:0:2" To="360"/>
            <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Children[1].ScaleX"
                Duration="0:0:2" To="0"/>
            <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.Children[1].ScaleY"
                Duration="0:0:2" To="0"/>
            <DoubleAnimation
                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                Duration="0:0:2.5" To="0"/>
        </Storyboard>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeftButtonDown">
            <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource MinimizeAnimations}"/>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Window.Triggers>
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="Like this" FontSize="40"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```